Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend_Controller_Request_Http' not found
Just an admin and not a Magento guy. Website was running well on Debian 11. Upgraded to Debian 12 and now am facing this error;

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend_Controller_Request_Http' not
found in
/storage/websites/agricomnew/app/code/local/Amasty/Fpc/Model/Fpc/Front.php:103
Stack trace: #0
/storage/websites/agricomnew/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(703):
Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front->__construct() #1
/storage/websites/agricomnew/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(685):
Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_getProcessor('Amasty_Fpc_Mode...') #2
/storage/websites/agricomnew/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(351):
Mage_Core_Model_Cache->processRequest() #3
/storage/websites/agricomnew/app/Mage.php(686):
Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) #4
/storage/websites/agricomnew/index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store') #5
{main} thrown in
/storage/websites/agricomnew/app/code/local/Amasty/Fpc/Model/Fpc/Front.php
on line 103

Have no clue on where to check and seeking some advice.
Magento version 1.9.4.0 with PHP 7.1 (same error with version 7.4)

what's php version and exact magento version?

Hey, i'd like to help, but w/o code its hard to reproduce. Can you share that code in private (NDA)? And ... think about to head over to OpenMage that far more up2date.

Hi there. appreciate help. Just realised that was running with php 8.2 which is not supported. Reverted to 7.4 and working now!
